# Facebook Graph API Service Temporarily Unavailable Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to connect a bot to Facebook messenger, using Facebook developer tools.
https://developers.facebook.com/

I've created the Facebook app, and it's sent me the webhook to my server. However, when trying to call the Graph API when sending a message back to the user, I receive the following error:

```
 FacebookMessaging:400 : {
   "error": {
      "message": "(#2) Service temporarily unavailable",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "is_transient": true,
      "code": 2,
      "fbtrace_id": "AIWsRyUmPFnySGwb1Rgl4P6"
   }
}
```

POST API,

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/page-id/messages?access_token=token
```

JSON

```
{recipient:{id:"id"}, message:{ text:"message"}}
```

I suspect it could be because my app is unreleased, but I'm trying to test it beforehand. Is there any other explanation for this, or how are you suppose to test an app before releasing it?

The same code is working for an older Facebook app that is released.

Comment: Just making sure: you're not actually trying to post to the v2.6 endpoint, right?

Comment: From fb examples, the recent version is v10.0 and v2.6 very very old. Did you try with recent versions?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages#url

Comment: changed to v10 and same error

Comment: ok, issue was that the API call was missing the access token, stupid mistake, but unusual error for missing the access token

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that the API call was missing the access token. Stupid mistake, but unusual error for missing the access token.

Answer (score 0):

I already try and reproduce this problem. May be you use wrong access_token in this case. When you want to send the message by page, use should use `page access token` instead of `user access token`

Check out the diff here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

And flow here for get page access token: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#pagetokens

Answer (score -1):

It is clearly return you the response with type as OAuthException. If you find this error type in facebook garph api error handling documentation. You can see the first line of error codes is OAuthException. Also it is written there the resolution of this type of error in what to do column is, If no subcode is present, the login status or access token has expired, been revoked, or is otherwise invalid. Get a new access token.
If a subcode is present, see the subcode.

Well it is nice to see you get the answer on your own.